# Split string when a capital letter follows a lower cap letter in the middle of a word in R

Tags: regex, string, r

I have some problems with different strings being concatenated and which I would like to split again.
I am dealing with things such as

```
name="o-n-Butylhydroxylamine1-MethylpropylhydroxylamineAmino-2-butanol"
```

which in this case should be split in
`"o-n-Butylhydroxylamine", "1-Methylpropylhydroxylamine"` and `"Amino-2-butanol"`

Any thoughts how I could use `strsplit` and/or `gsub` regular expression to achieve this?
The rule I would like to use is that I would like to split a word when either a number, a bracket ("(") or a capital letter follows a lower caps letter. Any thoughts how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use positive look-around assertions to find (and then split at) inter-character positions preceded by a lower case letter and succeeded by an upper case letter, a digit, or a `(`.

```
name <- "o-n-Butylhydroxylamine1-MethylpropylhydroxylamineAmino-2-butanol"
pat <- "(?<=[[:lower:]])(?=[[:upper:][:digit:](])"
strsplit(name, pat, perl=TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "o-n-Butylhydroxylamine"      "1-Methylpropylhydroxylamine"
# [3] "Amino-2-butanol"
```

Comment: Many thanks to all for the answers - I'll accept this one as it's closest to my exact question, but all seem to work perfectly!! thx!!

Comment: Josh, I am learning something here.  It looks like you can include the `(` within the `[ ]` set without needing to escape it.. do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta -- Yep, that's right. Quoting from `?regex`, "only `'^ - \ ]'` are special inside character classes" (where "character class" refers to that outer pair of brackets, `[]`).

Comment: This is a sexayyyy regex

Answer (score 3):

```
strsplit(name, "(?<=([a-z]))(?=[A-Z]|[0-9]|\\()", perl=TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "o-n-Butylhydroxylamine"      "1-Methylpropylhydroxylamine" "Amino-2-butanol"
```

Remember that the return value is a list, so use `[[1]]` if appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
name="o-n-Butylhydroxylamine1-MethylpropylhydroxylamineAmino-2-butanol"
print(strsplit(gsub("([a-z])(\\d)","\\1#\\2",
                    gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])","\\1#\\2",name)),"#")[[1]])
```

It assumes a non-cap letter followed by a digit is a split as well as a non-cap followed by a cap.

Comment: Ha wow cool - thanks so much!! You're really good at those regular expressions - I really need to read up on them!!