# Split vectors by uppercases and lower cases

Tags: r, regex

I've read some nice question about splitting uppercases and lowercases, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173774/split-string-when-a-capital-letter-follows-a-lower-cap-letter-in-the-middle-of-a), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988959/splitting-string-based-on-letters-case?lq=1), but I cannot manage to make them work with my data.

```
# here my data
    data <- data.frame(text = c("SOME UPPERCASES     And some Lower Cases"
                                ,"OTHER UPPER CASES   And other words"
                                , "Some lower cases        AND UPPER CASES"
                                ,"ONLY UPPER CASES"
                                ,"Only lower cases, maybe"
                                ,"UPPER lower UPPER!"))
    data
                                         text
    1 SOME UPPERCASES     And some Lower Cases
    2      OTHER UPPER CASES   And other words
    3  Some lower cases        AND UPPER CASES
    4                         ONLY UPPER CASES
    5                  Only lower cases, maybe
    6                        UPPER lower UPPER!
```

The desired result should be something like this:

```
       V1                  V2
1      SOME UPPERCASES     And some Lower Cases
2      OTHER UPPER CASES   And other words
3      AND UPPER CASES     Some lower cases        
4      ONLY UPPER CASES    NA
5      NA                  Only lower cases, maybe
6      UPPER UPPER!         lower
```

So separate all the words with uppercases only letters, from the others.

As test, I've tried only for one line some ways but none of them work well:

```
strsplit(x= data$text[1], split="[[:upper:]]")   # error
gsub('([[:upper:]])', ' \\1', data$text[1])      # not good results

library(reshape)
transform(data, FOO = colsplit(data$text[1], split = "[[:upper:]]", names = c('a', 'b')))                                        # neither good results
```

Comment: It is not clear what your rules are. You want to omit the `!` in the last row, but you keep `,` in the previous row. What are your precise rules here?

Comment: Thanks a lot, there was a typo, the punctuation follow the case of the previous letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data:

```
data <- data.frame(text = c("SOME UPPERCASES     And some Lower Cases"
                            ,"OTHER UPPER CASES   And other words"
                            , "Some lower cases        AND UPPER CASES"
                            ,"ONLY UPPER CASES"
                            ,"Only lower cases, maybe"
                            ,"UPPER lower UPPER!"))
```

code:

```
library(magrittr)

UpperCol    <- regmatches(data$text , gregexpr("\\b[A-Z]+\\b",data$text)) %>% lapply(paste, collapse = " ") %>% unlist
notUpperCol <- regmatches(data$text , gregexpr("\\b(?![A-Z]+\\b)[a-zA-Z]+\\b",data$text, perl = T)) %>% lapply(paste, collapse = " ") %>% unlist

result <- data.frame(I(UpperCol), I(notUpperCol))
result[result == ""] <- NA
```

result:

```
#           UpperCol            notUpperCol
#1   SOME UPPERCASES   And some Lower Cases
#2 OTHER UPPER CASES        And other words
#3   AND UPPER CASES       Some lower cases
#4  ONLY UPPER CASES                   <NA>
#5              <NA> Only lower cases maybe
#6       UPPER UPPER                  lower
```

---

- The trick is regex. So learn [regex](http://regex101.com)
- Thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew for some optimization.

Comment: Be careful with [`[A-z]+`, it does not only match letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926). Also, `(?![A-Z]+\\b)` should be put after the leading `\b` to be more efficient (=> `"\\b(?![A-Z]+\\b)[a-zA-Z]+\\b"`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that part is missing in my bag of tools, I need to learn (+1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. Both remarks are valuable!

Answer (score 1):

An approach using the [stringi](/questions/tagged/stringi) package:

```
library(stringi)
l1 <- stri_extract_all_regex(dat$text, "\\b[A-Z]+\\b")
l2 <- mapply(setdiff, stri_extract_all_words(dat$text), l1)

res <- data.frame(all_upper = sapply(l1, paste, collapse = " "),
                  not_all_upper = sapply(l2, paste, collapse = " "),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
res[res == "NA"] <- NA
res[res == ""] <- NA
```

which gives:

> ```
> > res
>           all_upper          not_all_upper
> 1   SOME UPPERCASES   And some Lower Cases
> 2 OTHER UPPER CASES        And other words
> 3   AND UPPER CASES       Some lower cases
> 4  ONLY UPPER CASES                   <NA>
> 5              <NA> Only lower cases maybe
> 6       UPPER UPPER                  lower
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
separate <- function(x) {
  x <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), "\\s+"))
  with_lower <- grepl("\\p{Ll}", x, perl = TRUE)
  list(paste(x[!with_lower], collapse = " "),  paste(x[with_lower], collapse = " "))
}


do.call(rbind, lapply(data$text, separate))

     [,1]                [,2]                     
[1,] "SOME UPPERCASES"   "And some Lower Cases"   
[2,] "OTHER UPPER CASES" "And other words"        
[3,] "AND UPPER CASES"   "Some lower cases"       
[4,] "ONLY UPPER CASES"  ""                       
[5,] ""                  "Only lower cases, maybe"
[6,] "UPPER UPPER!"      "lower"
```